# How do I create a split component with shared pins between symbol parts on altium?

Tags: altium, symbol

I'm trying to create a symbol for a dual op-amp on Altium designer, I want to have the symbols be the classic 5 pin representation of an op amp with both inputs, an output and the power pins.

But when I place the pins on both symbols the pin is repeated on the list, is this how it's supposed to work or do I need to do some special process to share those pins between parts?

[image: Symbols]
[image: Pins]

Comment: why do you need to define power pins on both symbols?

Comment: I don't "need to" I just want to avoid having a PartC with the power pins, I find it would be easier to read with the symbols like that.

Comment: I only place power pins on the first section. No need to have them on every one - that actually clutters the schematic even more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a property called "Part Number" in the schematic pin properties.  It's a bit convoluted as this field has a special meaning in some contexts.  You should start by reading and understanding the section on the "Part Number" field in the pin documentation here:

https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/sch-dlg-schcomponentpinspropertiesformcomponent-pin-editor-ad

The TL;DR is that for multi-symbol parts, you can set the pin's "sub-part" association by setting the "Part Number" field.  If  you set it to zero, it's a single pin that appears in all sub-parts.  It's best to play around with it to get a good feel for how it works...

Answer (score 1):

Altium's split components are a little dicky. To avoid this issue, I usually create the entire component, with correct pin numbers within the first part. Then create new parts, cut and paste, and everything should come out correct.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you mean create the entire symbol with just one pair of power pins and leaving them on the first part?

Comment: Yeah, why would you want to duplicate them?